# AngularJS + Jersey 2.x: SAML 2.0 SSO Login implementation

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, saml

1) Is it possible to do a SAML 2.0 SSO Interaction using an AngularJS 1.x SPA and Jersey 2.x backend web service api?

2) Has anyone done this before? I can't find too many examples.

My thoughts:

It seems like I can have certain endpoints that will http-post the saml assertion, send it to the idp and listen for their return post/get. Then I could redirect the client from their original login xaml style call.

Comment: Why should that be impossible? You can write any code you want in your front/backend. It doesn't sound too unusual so someone has probably done that as well. But that's not actually your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my experience.

1. I have Spring-mvc + AngualrJs web application.
2. Webapp is based on token authentication, written a Filter that checks
   authentication header.
3. Implemented SAML Authentication using spring-saml project.
4. Two main entity in SAM Authentication SP=ServiceProvider and
   IDP=IdentityProvider
5. I have shared my metadata or SP metadata to IDP & IDP share his
   metadata with me. for understanding communication protocol.
6. After successful login from IDP, we read response and generate my
   application authentication cookies.

spring website for generating SP metadata :http://saml-federation.appspot.com/saml

Note: You can test SAML authentication implementation on public hosted IDP called as [ssocircle](http://idp.ssocircle.com/)
SSOCircle IDP metadata URL: [ssocircle-metadata](http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml)